# Formatting string problems with replaceAll in Java

Tags: java, string, formatting

I have  a string:

```
String strung = (1.0√(10.0))/1.0
```

after making the following calls:

```
strung = strung.replaceAll(".0","");
strung = strung.replaceAll("1√","√");
```

I don't expect to get this:

```
(√())/1
```

I just need to get the following, but am having a hard time setting it up

```
√10
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Use `replace`, not `replaceAll`.

Comment: We'll assume you meant `strung = "(1.0√(10.0))/1.0";`. --- Both `replaceAll()` parameters are regex, first is find expression, second is replacement value. In both, there are special characters, and `.` is a special character matching *any* input character. You need to escape it: `replaceAll("\\.0","")`

Comment: I am confused. If you run two replace operations, neither of which removes parenthesis, why would you expect parenthesis to be removed?

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that trying to do symbolic manipulation of mathematical expressions using plain old string replacement is going to fail pretty hard, pretty fast.

Comment: I am not expecting the parentheses to be removed by the replaceAll calls I have. @Andreas

Comment: Doing string replacement of arbitrary substrings that might *sometimes* be eliminated with changing result, so a really, really bad idea. You need to *parse* the expression into an expression tree, then "optimize" that.

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for the tip on "." being a special character. Well, so far I've coded a JAVA calculator that solves linear and quadratic equations with replaceAll calls and equations being stored as strings with further manipulations with Pattern and Matcher objects, as well as replaceAll calls on the strings. It's worked nicely up to now, where I can get exact answers with simplified roots and approximate decimal answers.

Comment: @i_o I successfully opened a bottle of wine using that trick with a shoe, bashing it against a wall; doesn't mean it wouldn't have been much, much easier with a corkscrew. As in, sure, you *can* do it with string manipulation, but it's the wrong tool for the job, so you're just making your life hard.

Comment: So what method would you use instead of using replaceAll calls to format mathematical expressions @AndyTurner

Comment: @i_o like Andreas says above: "You need to parse the expression into an expression tree, then "optimize" that."

Comment: you mean like using reverse polish notation until you simplified the equation?? @AndyTurner

Comment: @i_o yes. Your current approach is just far too easy to confound. For example, how would your regexes above deal with `10.01`? The one replacing `".0"` with `""` would change that to `101`.

Comment: Luckily, I've only employed this method when finding exact answers in completing the square method of solving quadratic equations.. so replaceAll("\\.0") is only used to rid the double numbers that have been already manipulated in order to produce the exact answer.. I only use replaceAll("\\.0") when preparing the output once all the calculations have taken place @AndyTurner

Comment: Also, the user would only be allowed to use integers if he/she decides to use completing the square to solve the quadratic equation.. if he/she uses non-integers than the quadratic formula would be used.. so its impossible to end up with 10.01 when the user decides to use completing the square , since the code will be simplifying roots and fractions.. there will be no division allowed in this process @AndyTurner

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace`, not `replaceAll`.

`replaceAll`'s parameters are interpreted as a regular expression, and a regular expression replacement respectively. So, the `.` is interpreted as "any character".

`replace` takes the parameters literally, as in `"."` only matches periods in the string.

Of course, you can also continue using `replaceAll`, but escape the `.`:

```
strung = strung.replaceAll("\\.0","");
```

Comment: That was my first take too, and I left a comment to that effect, because that is not actually related to the question. If you read it again, OP wants `(1.0√(10.0))/1.0` converted to `√10`, but doesn't even do anything about the parenthesis, leaving me confused (see my second comment).

Comment: @Andreas well, sure. I interpreted it as confusion as to why OP ended up with this intermediate output, from which it was not possible to proceed to get the desired final output.